# Can't delete lines from a file, use a stringstream as an alternative?

Tags: c++, file, text, vector, edit

I've looked at ostream, istream, iostream, and fstream, and I still can't quite figure out how to simply delete lines from an input or output text file just as any clown can do with a text editor.

If I've got a file that reads, for example,

```
box 1\n
socks\n
box 2\n
pajamas\n
box 3\n
textbooks\n\eof
```

etc, and I want to totally delete the second box (the 3rd and 4th line) so that the text file reads

```
box 1\n
socks\n
box 3\n
textbooks\n\eof
```

I would evidently need to create a temporary file, and place only what I want to keep in that temp file, delete the original file, then rename the temp file with the name of the original file.  This is fine and dandy and I understand that it's actually how all programs handle document editing.  But it's a tedious pain in the ass to code.

What I'd REALLY love to be able to do is just manipulate what exists without jumping through all these hoops every time I manipulate my text, since I have a huge amount of stuff to sort through and edit.

So this is my hypothesis that I'd like some advice with.  Would it be easier to, upon opening the file, to store the entire contents of the file into a string, a vector, a dynamically allocated char array, or perhaps a stringstream, so that I can easily delete parts of it and rearrange it?  I could then dump my edited text into a temp text, delete the original, and rename the tempfile with the name of the original file.

Is there any validity to this, or is there a simpler way to do it?  I'm tempted to use vectors as my first guess.

[EDIT] Keep in mind that the file I'm dealing with isn't quite so nicely organized to merit the use of structs for easy manipulation of chunks of data.  It could be huge paragraphs of prose, or meaningless strings of digits.

Comment: If you store everything in memory, there is no need for a temp file as you can just overwrite the data in the original file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many lines and lots of changes, I'm tempted to use a `std::list` rather than a `std::vector`.

If you delete or insert often, then the lines must be rearranged. Doing that with a `std::vector` is more expensive than with a `std::list`.